# Default php.ini variable path locations (session.save_path, soap.wsdl_cache_dir, upload_tmp_dir)

Tags: php

I am wondering how the default values are determined for each of these values on windows, mac, linux:

- session.save_path
- soap.wsdl_cache_dir
- upload_tmp_dir

  1. Also are their any other php.ini variables that involve paths on the file system that you are aware of?
  2. Based on my investigation on windows it seems session.save_path is C:\Windows\Temp. Is this a safe location? When does this get deleted?

Comment: Session varaibles are stored at the server level. They are basically temp files that are created, then destroyed either by timing out or by the session_destroy() method. Usually, those values are set by default in the php.ini upon installation. Storing session data in the temp folder is normal and as long as you are doing good session cleanup and/or have the session timeout set decently, it's fine.

Comment: What happens if the temp folder gets cleared before the session expires? My basic question is: When does the temp folder on windows get cleared? and on mac (/tmp)

Comment: temp files only get cleaned out if you tell windows to clean them out. They are persistent until otherwise told to be deleted by an application. This is why, on windows, you have to do a cleanup regularly to keep that temp folder under control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How are default values determined

### `session.save_path`

For `session.save_path`, the php.ini defined value is used by default, otherwise the path is determined here:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/mod_files.c#L264

That calls `php_get_temporary_directory` which is defined here:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_open_temporary_file.c#L192

- If you're using windows, it uses the Win32 API call `GetTempPath` to get the temporary folder path (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- If you're using Unix, it uses the TMPDIR environment variable.
- If all else fails, it falls back to `/tmp`

### `soap.wsdl_cache_dir`

`soap.wsdl_cache_dir` attempts to use the defined php.ini value. If it isn't found it will default to `/tmp` via this code:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/soap/soap.c#L520

Read more about `STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY` here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_12.htm

### `upload_tmp_dir`

`upload_tmp_dir` is set to NULL (but will use a php.ini override), along with many default values, in:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/main.c#L579

```
STD_PHP_INI_ENTRY("upload_tmp_dir", NULL, PHP_INI_SYSTEM, OnUpdateStringUnempty, upload_tmp_dir, php_core_globals, core_globals)
```

and used in file upload here:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/rfc1867.c#L1006

```
fd = php_open_temporary_fd_ex(PG(upload_tmp_dir), "php", &temp_filename, 1 TSRMLS_CC);
```

This function, if an empty `upload_tmp_dir` is passed, defaults to using the `php_get_temporary_directory` function we mentioned earlier.

### Also are their any other php.ini variables that involve paths on the file system that you are aware of?

There are plenty. A quick look through https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/main.c shows plenty of default configs that use paths (`open_basedir`, `include_path`, `sys_temp_dir`, `extension_dir` and `error_log` to name just a few). In addition, extensions have their own collection of configurations that could include path parameters.

### Based on my investigation on windows it seems session.save_path is C:\Windows\Temp. Is this a safe location? When does this get deleted?

When openning temporary files on Windows, PHP sets the permission to be exclusive to the user running your webserver, which should mean only it, and administrators, would be able to access the contents of the file:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_open_temporary_file.c#L149